# Su or sudo not accepting password

Tags: ubuntu, passwords, sudo

Pretty straight forward.  I have an ubuntu 9.10 NBR fresh install, and su nor sudo will accept my password from the command line.  I can use synaptic and the updater tool, as well as invoke things with gksudo, but not invoke with sudo or su in the terminal.

The password is standard 8 character, 2 upper case letters, 2 numbers, and the rest lower case letters.  But it says the password is incorrect.

As stated, this is a fresh install, I haven't fiddled with any settings.  Am I missing a step? Or is there something horribly wrong.

Comment: My current work around is invoking "gksudo gnome-terminal" and it seems to work.  Odd, yet it works.

Comment: I'm guessing you're attempting to `su` into the root account?  By default Ubuntu doesn't have a root password, so `su` should not work.  If you need a root shell you can do a `sudo su -`.

It's hard to tell what you mean by `sudo` not working.  Does it give an error message?  Does it say your password is incorrect?

Comment: Any non-ASCII characters in your password that might confuse a broken console app? Does setting a new `passwd` for the user fix it?

Comment: could you post your /etc/sudoers file please?

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps this link will be of help ...
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RootSudo

Answer (score 0):

Character set issue?  Does your terminal agree with X about what character set you're using?

Answer (score -1):

i found this quick and easy way to reset ubuntu user password:
http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/linux/reset-your-forgotten-ubuntu-password-in-2-minutes-or-less/

i was messing around with /etc/passwd and /etc/shadow and some how lost my ability to use sudo, and then realized my user password got changed or deleted some how.

glhf!
-outeran

Comment: The Asker was trying to figure out why `su` did not work, but why `gksu` did work, not how to reset their password.